# ASP.NET MVC 3 Route Constraint : Regular Expression for not null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a route constraint but not sure what would be the best for this. Here is the route with no constraint :

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Accommodation_accomm_tags",
    "accomm/{controller}/{action}/{tag}",
    new { action = "Tags", controller = "AccommProperty" },
    new { tag = @"" } //Here I would like to put a RegEx for not null match
);
```

What would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need a constraint for a not null/empty match? Normally if you define your route like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Accommodation_accomm_tags",
    "accomm/{controller}/{action}/{tag}",
    new { action = "Tags", controller = "AccommProperty" },
);
```

and `tag` is not specified in the request url this route simply won't match.

And if you want a token to be optional, then:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Accommodation_accomm_tags",
    "accomm/{controller}/{action}/{tag}",
    new { action = "Tags", controller = "AccommProperty", tag = UrlParameter.Optional },
);
```

Constraints are used when you want to constrain the value of a given route token to some specific format.

Comment: You nailed it again. I was trying to remember that there should be a some easy way for that but I couldn't. now it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: What if your action waiting for string parameter? In this case, if you'll specify tag as optional parameter  it will contain null value.

Answer (score 8):

Could you create an `IRouteConstraint`:

```
public class NotNullRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
  public bool Match(
    HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, 
    RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
  {
    return (values[parameterName] != null);
  }
}
```

Which you can wire up:

```
context.MapRoute(
  "Accommodation_accomm_tags",
  "accomm/{controller}/{action}/{tag}",
  new { action = "Tags", controller = "AccommProperty" },
  new { tag = new NotNullRouteConstraint() }
);
```

Comment: I thought that too and this will be the solution if I cannot find a RegEx for not null. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

At first, I tried to create a RegEx for empty string which is `^$` (which is what null would be). However, it doesn't look like route constraints can be `!=`. How about matching one or more character with `^.+$`?

So:

```
tag = @"^.+$"
```

Comment: you have two sentences which are totally opposite to each other : `I believe you want a RegEx for empty string...` and `...you want not empty string of course...`

Comment: Well he asks for a RegExp for null which is actually empty string but he wants the opposite of that for the route constraint.

Comment: I clearly pointed out that I need a RegEx for not null string. you can see it as comment inside my code sample : `//Here I would like to put a RegEx for not null match` I didn't ask for null match RegEx anywhere. Sorry but appreciate your effort though.

Comment: @bzlm it wasn't there. see the update history : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7501141/revisions

Comment: @Cymen he he :) thanks, gonna give it a try. (don't hit the coffee hard though, not so healthy. you know what I mean :))